# Python; Not sure where I'm going wrong with web scraper

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below is the code I am working on. I am trying to scrape the historical data table that is located at nasdaq.com. I have it referencing a list of stocks compiled in an excel worksheet (can provide if needed,however not the issue). I am having a hard time identifying the table as well as being able to call the correct tag. I tried to follow an online tutorial with no avail.

When I run the code, in the python shell I just get shown empty brackets every few seconds.

```
<code>
    import webbrowser, selenium, os, pyautogui, select, time, openpyxl,

    bs4, requests, subprocess

    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select




    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('StockList.xlsx')

    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Merged')



    for row in range (2,211):

        def clean_history(sel, domains):
            temp = sel.get_location()
            for domain in domains:
                sel.open(domain)
                sel.delete_all_visible_cookies()
            sel.open(temp)
        url = sheet['B' + str(row)].value


        root_url = 'http://www.nasdaq.com'
        index_url = root_url + '/symbol/' + url + '/historical'

        def get_data():
            response = requests.get(index_url)
            soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
            return [div.attrs.get('td') for tr in  

    soup.select('div.quotes_content_left_pn1AJAX')]

        print(get_data())

</code>
```

Edit:

I only just taught myself python, hence the poor reiterations. I followed a book I picked up for some of this. And the actual interaction of the webpage I followed this link.

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-python

I believe I am mislabeling something in the line of code with the Return line. I want to be able to take this data and store it as a text file or csv, or anything easily readable for further manipulation.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Also, I just taught myself python a few weeks ago. The imports up top are simply because i was automating mouse clicks and stuff to download a csv file of this historical data. If an explanation or alternative to get this information could be given that'd be fanstastic.   I am trying to figure out why its not returning any values.

Comment: Not sure what tutorial you have been following but defining the same function repeatedly in a for loop is not good ever. As for your code,  you need to share what does not work and what it needs to do to be correct